# Change the default branch for each configured Git Remote

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I know you can change the default remote for a branch by doing:

`git push -u remote branch`

But I have a few remotes, and I want to just be able to do:

`git pull remote1`
`git push remote2`

And have a default branch for each remote (probably the same, but not necessarily).

I was hoping to avoid doing `git pull remote branch` and `git push remote branch` each time.

My current config has this:

```
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
```

And that is just from doing the aforementioned `git push -u ...` for my 'primary' remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three-way ("triangular") work-flows are not all that well supported in Git, but for certain special cases, `git config push.default` can be set usefully, and in other special cases, `remote.remote.pushurl` can be set usefully.

The problem at the most fundamental level is that any one branch can only have one *upstream* set; the upstream combines both the name of the remote and the name of the branch as found on that remote, so if branch *B* has upstream *U* set, running `git push` with no arguments pushes to the (single) assigned remote, using the (single) assigned name, and `git pull` fetches from the (same, single) assigned remote and merges from the (same) single assigned name.

Using `git push -u` is just a short way to say: *after my `git push` succeeds, please run `git branch --set-upstream-to` for me as well*.  Since that sets the (one, single) upstream, it's almost certainly not what you want to do here: either the upstream is already set correctly, or you want to set it *before* (not after) the `git push` command.

Your *best* best here is probably to *stop using `git push` and `git pull`*.  Instead of those commands, write your own command(s), that use your own configuration setup(s) to do whatever it is you want done.  Run those commands, not `git push` and `git pull`.  (Those commands will then eventually run Git commands, maybe even `git push` and `git pull`, but with appropriate remote names and refspecs.)

Failing that, look into the settings available for `push.default`, `push.defaultRemote`, and `remote.name.push`, as well as the above-mentioned `remote.remote.pushurl` settings, all described in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).